# Use a local user selected TTF file in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm developing a Flutter app where a user will be able to download TTF fonts from wherever they wish, and then use it from within the app using file picker.

I've searched around in the internet, but came up empty. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Okay I figured it out myself.

We can use the `loadFontFromList` function. [Details here](https://master-docs-flutter-io.firebaseapp.com/flutter/dart-ui/loadFontFromList.html).